# Finding $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(1+A\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Q2) **Cards**\begin{align} J & = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} \ln \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x 
\\ Q & = \int_{0}^{J/2} \ln \left(1+A\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x  
\\ K & = \int_{0}^{8} e^{Q/J}\,\mathrm{d}A\end{align}

Four special cards in a deck of cards are in an unknown forest. Their kingdom is **190km** away. Their vehicles' speed (in **km/h**) is given by $K$. They depart at **8AM** and must reach the castle before midnight. Can the **KING** make it on time?

---

I'm stuck, all my attempts were futile. Please help or give hints.
Final answer in the answer key is: $K = \dfrac{38}3$ and king takes $15$ hours to get there so he makes it in time.

EDIT: I was able to solve for $J$ using integration by parts. Inspired from @Dhanvi Sreenivasan who told in his answer this can be solved by applying integration by parts (I didn't use the exact method he suggested though as it was a little lengthy):

[image]

Proof of $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t = 0$ is below:

[image]

Since $J = \pi$,
$$Q = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(1+A\cos^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$K=\int_{0}^{8} e^{Q/\pi}\,\mathrm{d}A.$$

Now the question boils down to: how to solve for $Q$?

PS: We are not allowed to use the concept of partial derivatives as this was not taught in this 12th grade course.

Comment: Doesn't the answer key give some method or hint? or atleast can you show why you feel your efforts are futile.

Comment: I believe that partial derivatives/2D integration (the second one being a disguise for the first one) is inevitable in the calculation of $Q$. Are you sure this is really a problem for 12th grade?

Comment: We were taught 2D integration. Not partial derivatives. @Saad

Comment: @Sid I'd write an answer soon, but the leap from a 1D integral to a 2D one will seem artificial without knowledge of partial differentiation.

Comment: Your integral reminds me of Jensen's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula), although I'm not sure if it can actually be applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$F(a):=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(1+a\cos^2 x) \,dx\text{ for }a>0$$

Now,
$$\ln(1+a \cos^2 x)=\int_{y=0}^{y=a} \frac{1}{1+y\cos^2 x}\:d(1+y \cos^2  x)=\int_0^a \frac{\cos^2 x}{1+y\cos^2 x}\:dy$$
Therefore, we have
$$F(a)=\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}}\color{green}{\int _0^a}\frac{\cos^2 x}{1+y\cos^2 x}\,\color{green}{dy}\,\color{blue}{dx}$$
Now, change the order of integration to obtain

$$F(a)=\color{green}{\int_{0}^{a}}\color{blue}{\int _0^{\pi/2}}\frac{\cos^2 x}{1+y\cos^2 x}\,\color{blue}{dx}\,\color{green}{dy}$$
The inner integral is easy to evaluate. Note that

\begin{align}
\int _0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2 x}{\color{red}{1}+y\cos^2 x}\,dx&=\frac{1}{y}\int _0^{\pi/2}\left\{1-\frac{1}{\color{red}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}+y\cos^2 x}\right\}\:dx \\
&=\frac{1}{y}\int _0^{\pi/2}\left\{1-\frac{\sec^2 x}{(1+y)+\tan^2 x}\right\}\:dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2y}-\frac{1}{y}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d(\tan x)}{(y+1)+\tan^2 x} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left\{\frac{\sqrt{y+1}-1}{y\sqrt{y+1}}\right\}
\end{align}

The problem reduces to finding
$$F(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^a \left\{\frac{\sqrt{y+1}-1}{y\sqrt{y+1}}\right\} \:dy  $$
Make the change of variable $y=u^2-1$, so that $dy=2u\;du$. The integral becomes

\begin{align}\int_1^{\sqrt{a+1}} \frac{u-1}{u(u^2-1)}\cdot2u\:du&=2\int_1^{\sqrt{a+1}} \frac{du}{u+1} \\ &=2\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+1}+1}{2}\right) \end{align}

Now, $$Q=F(A)=\pi\cdot\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A+1}+1}{2}\right)}$$

By the hypothesis of the problem, we have
$$K=\int_0^8 \exp{\left(\frac{Q}{J}\right)} \;dA=\int_0^8 \frac{\sqrt{A+1}+1}{2} \:dA=\frac{38}{3}$$
as desired.

Comment: Very nice solution. Can you link me to a website containing the proof of: changing the order of integration will yield the same result.

Comment: In your solution lines 4-5 you apply this property

Comment: It is known as Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$**Lemma:** If $a, b > 0$ are constants, then$$
> I(a, b) := \int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \ln(a^2 \sin^2 x + b^2 \cos^2 x) \,\d x = π \ln \frac{a + b}{2}.
> $$

*Proof:* Note that\begin{gather*}
\int_a^b \frac{2c \cos^2 x}{a^2 \sin^2 x + c^2 \cos^2 x} \,\d c = \ln(a^2 \sin^2 x + c^2 \cos^2 x) \biggr|_{c = a}^{c = b},
\end{gather*}
thus\begin{gather*}
\small I(a, b) - I(a, a) = \int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \int_a^b \frac{2c \cos^2 x}{a^2 \sin^2 x + c^2 \cos^2 x} \,\d c \d x = \int_a^b \int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac{2c}{a^2 \tan^2 x + c^2} \,\d x \d c. \tag{1}
\end{gather*}
Because for $c ≠ a$,\begin{gather*}
\small\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac{1}{a^2 \tan^2 x + c^2} \,\d x = \int_0^{+∞} \frac{1}{a^2 t^2 + c^2} · \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} \,\d t = \frac{1}{a^2 - c^2} \int_0^{+∞} \left( \frac{a^2}{a^2 t^2 + c^2} - \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} \right) \,\d t\\
= \frac{1}{a^2 - c^2} \left. \left( \frac{a}{c} \arctan\frac{at}{c} - \arctan t \right) \right|_0^{+∞} = \frac{π}{2} · \frac{1}{c (a + c)},
\end{gather*}
so$$
(1) = \int_a^b 2c · \frac{π}{2} · \frac{1}{c (a + c)} \,\d c = π \int_a^b \frac{\d c}{a + c} = π(\ln(a + b) - \ln(2a)).
$$
Since $I(a, a) = π\ln a$, then\begin{gather*}
I(a, b) = π(\ln(a + b) - \ln(2a)) + π\ln a = π \ln \frac{a + b}{2}. \tag*{$\square$}
\end{gather*}

Now return to the problem. Since $1 + A\cos^2 x = \sin^2 x + (A + 1) \cos^2 x$, applying the lemma yields$$
Q(A) = \int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \ln(1 + A \cos^2 x) \,\d x = π\ln\left( \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{A + 1}) \right).
$$
Therefore,$$
K = \int_0^8 \exp\left( \frac{Q(A)}{π} \right) \,\d A = \int_0^8 \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{A + 1}) \,\d A = \frac{38}{3}.
$$

Comment: Lemma is so unintuitive... How will one come up with this in an exam?

Comment: @Sid This lemma is simply to make the answer fancier and easier to see how the integral is calculated. In a real exam, one would probably solve the integral directly by the same approach in the lemma but with $a=\sqrt{A+1}$ and $b=1$ plugged in (since $I(a,b)=I(b,a)$).

Answer (score 0):

For J, use the property that

$$J = \int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\ln(\frac{x}{1-x})dx = \int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\ln(\frac{1-x}{x})dx $$

$$\implies 2J = \int_0^1\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)\ln(\frac{1-x}{x})dx$$

You can calculate this integral (using integration by parts), to get

$$J = \pi$$

**HINT**

To simplify the integral, consider $u = \ln \frac{1-x}{x}$, $dv = \frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$

You can observe that $v = 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Now can you attempt the rest?

To solve for $Q$, i'd consider differentiating both sides wrt $A$, solving the integral for $x$, and then back integrating to get $Q(A)$ It will have mostly $\ln$ terms, so that should simplify quite well for calculating $K$